# Why the cancellationToken not cancell the download at the middle?

Tags: .net, console-application, task-parallel-library, cancellationtokensource

I am downloading a 1GB file and I am trying to cancel, if I am fast and I press 'c' to cancel, the cancellation is donde, but if the downloan began, then the process download all the file, and at the end, the flag "Cancelled" is true

Why the cancellationToken not cancell the download at the middle?

```
using System.Net;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
Console.WriteLine("Downloading a 100MB file...");


var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

DownloadFileWithToken(cancellationToken);



Console.WriteLine("Press C, to cancel the download");
if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'c')
{
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    Console.WriteLine("\n\rCancellation Sent");
}


Console.ReadLine();


 void DownloadFileWithToken(CancellationToken token)
{
    const string file1Gb = "https://speed.hetzner.de/1GB.bin";

    var webClient = new WebClient();

    token.Register(() => webClient.CancelAsync());
    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.BytesReceived);
    };

    webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {


        if (!e.Cancelled)
        {
            byte[] data = (byte[])e.Result;
            Console.WriteLine($"\nDownload Completed: {data.Length}");
        }
        else
        {

            Console.WriteLine("\nDownload canceled");
        }
    };

    webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(file1Gb));

}
```

Example of cancelling fast:

[image: Cancelling Fast]

Example of trying to cancell after the download began

[image: Trying to cancel when the download began]

[image: The download is cancelled, but the entire file was downloaded]

Comment: Have a look at: https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-support-the-http-request-cancelation-in-net-core-4b5561d9605d

Comment: [WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-7.0#remarks): "We don't recommend that you use the WebClient class for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class."

Comment: And [CancelAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.cancelasync?view=net-7.0#remarks): "Starting in .NET Core 2.0, CancelAsync doesn't cancel the request immediately if the response has started to fetch. For optimum cancellation behavior, use the HttpClient class instead of WebClient.". I'd always recommend you *read the documentation* if you're seeing behaviour you do not expect.